# How to add a value to an entity reference field set to unlimited values using entity metadata wrapper

Tags: entities

Im new to drupal and im trying to perform this operation, can some one help me on how can i add a new value to an entity reference field that its been set to hold unlimited values using the entity metadata wrapper only
this is what i have tried

```
$ewrapper->entity-reference-field->set($value);
```

this will overwrite the current value and i want to add to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$wrapper->field_foobar[] = $additional_value`;

Just change field_foobar to the machine name of your entity reference field.

The empty brackets insure a new value is added rather than overwriting existing value(s).

Good luck!